# Efficient read and write CSV in Go

Tags: csv, go

The Go code below reads in a 10,000 record CSV (of timestamp `times` and float `values`), runs some operations on the data, and then writes the original values to another CSV along with an additional column for `score`. However it is terribly slow (i.e. hours, but most of that is `calculateStuff()`) and I'm curious if there are any inefficiencies in the CSV reading/writing I can take care of.

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/csv"
  "log"
  "os"
  "strconv"
)

func ReadCSV(filepath string) ([][]string, error) {
  csvfile, err := os.Open(filepath)

  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  defer csvfile.Close()

  reader := csv.NewReader(csvfile)
  fields, err := reader.ReadAll()

  return fields, nil
}

func main() {
  // load data csv
  records, err := ReadCSV("./path/to/datafile.csv")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  // write results to a new csv
  outfile, err := os.Create("./where/to/write/resultsfile.csv"))
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Unable to open output")
  }
  defer outfile.Close()
  writer := csv.NewWriter(outfile)

  for i, record := range records {
    time := record[0]
    value := record[1]

    // skip header row
    if i == 0 {
      writer.Write([]string{time, value, "score"})
      continue
    }

    // get float values
    floatValue, err := strconv.ParseFloat(value, 64)
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal("Record: %v, Error: %v", floatValue, err)
    }

    // calculate scores; THIS EXTERNAL METHOD CANNOT BE CHANGED
    score := calculateStuff(floatValue)

    valueString := strconv.FormatFloat(floatValue, 'f', 8, 64)
    scoreString := strconv.FormatFloat(prob, 'f', 8, 64)
    //fmt.Printf("Result: %v\n", []string{time, valueString, scoreString})

    writer.Write([]string{time, valueString, scoreString})
  }

  writer.Flush()
}
```

I'm looking for help making this CSV read/write template code as fast as possible. For the scope of this question we need not worry about the `calculateStuff` method.

Comment: How slow is 'terribly slow'? What is the file size of the csv file you are testing? Because the word 'slow' is subjective...

Comment: Assuming the calculation is dependant only on the current record (e.g. you don't need to total all values of a column, or sort, or somesuch) don't suck in the whole file into memory but instead operate on each record as it it's read, the write it out. Avoid things like `ioutil.ReadAll` when you can instead operate on a stream. In any case, unless you're swapping (due to using too much memory) you're likely IO bound.

Comment: Also, make sure to check for errors!! E.g. https://play.golang.org/p/CBzz4lImW2

Comment: Also, if this the entire program (i.e. if it's not a part of a larger program) it makes more sense not to muck with file names but just read from `os.Stdin` and write to `os.Stdout` and let the shell handle opening files (or using direct output/input from/to other programs!) for you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're loading the file in memory first then processing it, that can be slow with a big file.

You need to loop and call `.Read` and process one line at a time.

```
func processCSV(rc io.Reader) (ch chan []string) {
    ch = make(chan []string, 10)
    go func() {
        r := csv.NewReader(rc)
        if _, err := r.Read(); err != nil { //read header
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer close(ch)
        for {
            rec, err := r.Read()
            if err != nil {
                if err == io.EOF {
                    break
                }
                log.Fatal(err)

            }
            ch <- rec
        }
    }()
    return
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/GoRVXp05cm)

//note it's roughly based on DaveC's comment.

Answer (score 7):

This is essentially [Dave C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55504/dave-c)'s answer from the comments sections:

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/csv"
  "log"
  "os"
  "strconv"
)

func main() {
  // setup reader
  csvIn, err := os.Open("./path/to/datafile.csv")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  r := csv.NewReader(csvIn)

  // setup writer
  csvOut, err := os.Create("./where/to/write/resultsfile.csv"))
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Unable to open output")
  }
  w := csv.NewWriter(csvOut)
  defer csvOut.Close()

  // handle header
  rec, err := r.Read()
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  rec = append(rec, "score")
  if err = w.Write(rec); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  for {
    rec, err = r.Read()
    if err != nil {
      if err == io.EOF {
        break
      }
      log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // get float value
    value := rec[1]
    floatValue, err := strconv.ParseFloat(value, 64)
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal("Record, error: %v, %v", value, err)
    }

    // calculate scores; THIS EXTERNAL METHOD CANNOT BE CHANGED
    score := calculateStuff(floatValue)

    scoreString := strconv.FormatFloat(score, 'f', 8, 64)
    rec = append(rec, scoreString)

    if err = w.Write(rec); err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
  w.Flush()
  }
}
```

Note of course the logic is all jammed into `main()`, better would be to split it into several functions, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

`encoding/csv` is indeed very slow on big files, as it performs a lot of allocations. Since your format is so simple I recommend using `strings.Split` instead which is much faster.

If even that is not fast enough you can consider implementing the parsing yourself using `strings.IndexByte` which is implemented in assembly: http://golang.org/src/strings/strings_decl.go?s=274:310#L1

Having said that, you should also reconsider using `ReadAll` if the file is larger than your memory.

Comment: A faster implementation using `bufio.Scanner` and `bytes.LastIndex` might look something like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/SYG9dQV-ir). It's ~3x faster than `encoding/csv` but that's at the expense of a lot of the error checking and flexibility that `encoding/csv` provides.